# Hex to AScii conversion going wrong in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hex, buffer, ascii

Okay first of all thank you for your time. This has been driving me crazy.

So after a lot of digging I'm now properly "talking" with a scale through RS232 which means talking to it using HEX.

So I've been able to send data to the scale and get it back as needed. What I'm getting when I process it on node.js though is making me crazy.

The raw data coming through after concatenation is

```
<Buffer 06 02 30 32 1b 33 1b 31 31 34 34 35 1b 30 30 30 31 32 30 1b 30 30 31 33 37 33 03>
```

Which I'm properly converting to string like this:

```
var coiso = Buffer.from(Buffer.concat(porquinho), 'ascii').toString('hex');
```

And getting as a result this:

```
060230321b331b31313434351b3030303132301b30303133373303
```

If I get this value onto any online HEX to ASCII website (for example [this](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.html)) the result I'm getting is the correct one which should be:

```
02311445000120001373
```

However if I use any javascript function in node for the conversion including the same that website uses:

```
function OnConvert(doom)
    {
        hex = doom;
        hex = hex.match(/[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}/g);
        len = hex.length;
        if( len==0 ) return;
        txt='';
        for(i=0; i<len; i++)
        {
            h = hex[i];
            code = parseInt(h,16);
            t = String.fromCharCode(code);
            txt += t;
        }
        return txt;
    }
```

The result I get without exception is this:

```
0214450012001373
```

Which is completely different as I'm losing one digit of the weight in the scale as well as one digit from the calculated price!

What the f*ck am I doing wrong here?

Please Help me out... It's driving me nuts!

Thank you in advance,

Kind Regards:

João Moreira

**UPDATE** As pointed out in the comments by ChrisG, if you use the exact same function in the browser the result is correct (check it -> [codepen](https://jsfiddle.net/2ko46wz0/))! Is this some node.js quirk???? I'm using node v8.9.3.

Comment: The result I'm getting is `��02�3�11445�000120�001373�` https://jsfiddle.net/2ko46wz0/

Comment: Thank you very much @ChrisG ! Now the plot thickens! could you try the same function in node.js and see if you also get the same result? That way I'll know if it's a problem with my node version somehow...

Answer (score 0):

So after A LOT of testing and digging I noticed the results in node were different in the windows commandline (I was on a mac).

So after I tested for the length of the string instead of its content I found out that it was exactly the same everywhere which basically means this is a problem with the content of the string being perceived as something else by the command line... thank you very much Apple!

So if you work with SERIAL PORTS and communication protocols that envolve HEX or ASCII maybe it's best if you don't use the command line for it.

Just a small advice people!!!

Comment: I'm guessing the issue mostly stems from the fact that some of these hex values aren't display characters like `3` or `A`. `1b` for instance is 27 in decimal, which is the ASCII code for the Escape key. Outputting that to a console window can have all kinds of unexpected results. If you look at the RAW input data, you can see that it's mostly numbers, like hex `30` is dec `48` is '0'. So the key to solving this issue is to parse the numbers before outputting them.